# Storing blobs in Elastic Search documents

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am storing a load of documents in ES whereby I have some attributes of the document to allow me to do some basic queries but I am also storing a fairly large XML blob of all the data to allow me to pull that out when I need.

Now as the data has grown the queries has gotten slower (dis-proportionally) especially through Kibana.

I can exclude certain fields from the search query but am I right in saying that because ES is document based, it still has to read the whole document (including the blob) from disk, even though it won't be returning the blob? Or does ES/Lucene do some magic to avoid that?

Comment: If you're running a search query, you'll be running on indexed data and not on the source. If you're talking about loading of source along with search result, you can disable that completely by setting `"_source": "false"` or load only certain source fields. Reference: [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-source-filtering.html)

Comment: @VarunNatraaj - but internally, won't ElasticSearch, which calls Lucene, be reading the WHOLE document from disk, and then filtering out in memory, before returning the results